# Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. > java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, build.gradle, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I just tried to set firestore with my flutter app. Affter doing it when I tried to run and debug my app 2  error was shown:

1. Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Harsh\flutter_projects\Coach Ui\code_ui\build\app\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\example\code_ui \BuildConfig.java (The system cannot find the path specified)

2)Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

Build Gradle under app (only provided main code in question)

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.code_ui"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
 }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build gradle under android

```
     dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
   }
   }
```

Dependencies Under pubspec

```
 dependencies:
 flutter:
 sdk: flutter


 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
firebase_auth: ^0.16.1 
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way:

1. Build gradle under Android folder:

   change: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

   to: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`
2. Run this on your terminal from the root of your Flutter project:

   flutter clean
3. Also, uninstall the app from your emulator/device and finally build it.

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build -> Clean Project  ->  Worked for me